# complex nested list comprehensions, PEP8

Tags: python, coding-style, list-comprehension

let's suppose I have code like this:

```python
questions = [{
    "title": q.title,
    "votes": q.get_total_votes(),
    "options": [{
        "title": o.title,
        "votes": o.votes
    } for o in q.get_options()]
} for q in queue.get_questions()]
```

But most of the PEP8 examples say I should write like this:

```python
questions = [{"title": q.title,
              "votes": q.get_total_votes(),
              "options": [{"title": o.title, "votes": o.votes}
                          for o in q.get_options()]}
             for q in queue.get_questions()]
```

Is the second version preferrable / more readable? Or maybe the list comprehensions are not the best way to do this and I should do plain

```python
questions = []
for q in queue.get_questions():
    options = []
    for o in q.get_options():
        options.append({"title": o.title, "votes": o.votes})
    questions.append({"title": q.title,
                      "votes": q.get_total_votes(),
                      "options": options})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PEP8 way is the best, not only is it readable but in the future you can amend it quite easily. The first way is also readable but not great because not all your keys are lined up as nicely and you have to tab nest your options keys, plus if you were viewing this with a smaller terminal(if you use vim or any terminal editor) then it'd be annoying. Just my thoughts though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like this which I think is more readable:

```
questions = [{"title": q.title,
              "votes": q.get_total_votes(),
              "options": [{"title": o.title, "votes": o.votes}
                            for o in q.get_options()]}
            for q in queue.get_questions()]
```